# Can I share a single folder in Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, sharing

I have some information I need to pass along, but also keep work-related information in my Dropbox. I'd like to share one folder but not all.

Answer (score 1):

Open your local Dropbox directory and open a context menu on the directory you want to share. The Dropbox entry offers an option to make it public. The exact name of that entry depends on your language.